# Movesense ECG recorder (Android) does not record ECG after firmware update from 1.9x to 2.x

Tags: movesense

I was testing MAX-ECG-MONITOR sensor (https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/evaluation-hardware-and-software/evaluation-boards-kits/max-ecgmonitor.html#eb-overview) using the Movesense ECG recorder app (Android). The firmware version was 1.9x. It worked as expected. I then updated the firmware to 2.x using the Movesense Showcase App. After this update, the Movesense ECG recorder app shows the heart-rate values but does not display or record ECG.

Is anyone experiencing the same problem?

Thank you!

I tried to use another version of the firmware, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Which firmware did you update on the sensor? The Movesense ECG Recorder has been tested with default_firmware both 2.1.5 and 2.2.0, and it should work.